# Есть ли смысл ставить значение ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism больше кол-ва ядер процессора?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, распараллеливание

Есть ли смысл ставить значение ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism больше кол-ва ядер процессора?

Видел, что некоторые в коде ставят MaxDegreeOfParallelism на 1 меньше, количества ядер в прцоессоре, что бы оставить 1 ядро системе, а некоторые вообще умножают кол-во ядер процессора на какую-то константу.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу, те примеры, что я видел - были основаны на Environment.ProcessorCount. Так же хотел бы дополнить вопрос следующим: если используется Hyper-threading - стоит ли ставить потоки по числу только физических ядер, либо по сумме числа физических и виртуальных ядер? Есть ли толк от виртуальных ядер в данной задаче?

Comment: Ну, если у вас при обработке много блокирующих операций ожидания, то по идее можно? Не уверен.

Comment: Правильный ответ будет такой - все зависит от Вашей задачи. А так, как она неизвестна, то и давать какие то рекомендации нет никакого смысла. Но есть один надежный способ - профилирование.  Запускайте задачу с одним, потом двумя и так дальше. А потом посмотрите время выполнения. Можно даже графики построить. И это будет правильное число для Вашей конкретной задачи.

А боятся hyper-treading не нужно. В современных процессорах он почти не оказывает существенного влияния на работу.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну задачи, которые используют MaxDegreeOfParallelism - обычно банальные. Работа с большими списками. Как пример - есть список в 1 000 000 строк, нужно его максимально быстро обойти и найти колл-во вхождений какой либо строки в список.

Comment: @KoVadim, по профилированию понятно. Но! - железо у всех разное, и то значение которое покажет у меня оптимальную производительность - может перегружать систему у конечного пользователя, либо не нагружать вообще, в следствии чего - потеря производительности.

Comment: Для начала протестируйте на паре-другой систем. Посмотрите. Возможно, что Вы быстро найдете тот оптимум. Если Вам нужно, что бы на каждой системе было "супер-оптимально" - напишите небольшой бенчмарк и дайте пользователю возможность его запустить и определить оптимальное  значение параметра.

Но как показывает практика, иногда нужно поменять алгоритм, что бы получить ускорение.

Comment: Тогда назревает еще вопрос, если вообще снять ограничение согласно документации: "If it is -1, there is no limit on the number of concurrently running operations." - что произойдет? Документация от MS конечно оставляет желать лучшего...

Comment: В принципе, -1 ядро от общего количества имеет смысл, особенно при тяжелых задачах с долго живущими потоками. Это даст возможность не потерять управление системой при подвисании вашей программы. А для подстройки под "сферическую" систему можно использовать конфигурацию приложения для "маньяков" и настройки  по-умолчанию для средне-статистической целевой системы.

Comment: @rdorn, тем не менее остается открытым вопрос Hyper-threading-а, физических и виртуальных ядер. Очень жаль что Eric Lippert ушел от дел с C#, был бы человек, который реально понимал ситуацию и отвечал на вопросы.

Comment: @Align hyper-treading - штука аппаратная и очень низкоуровневая. AMD используют настоящие ядра на низкой частоте, Intel - hyper-treading на высокой частоте, так что то на то по сути получается. Как и моногопоточность - если потоки живут мало, то дополнительные ядра могут и не принимать участие в реальной работе. Нынешние ОС не умеют равномерно нагружать доступные ядра, то ли в угоду тепло- и энерго-эффективности, то ли еще по чему, но факт остается фактом, пока одно ядро справляется - остальные будут прохлаждаться

Answer (score 1):

Смысла никакого нет ставить какое либо значение.

ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism определяет верхнюю планку, а реальное количество потоков будет определено количеством свободных потоков в пуле. В свою очередь количество потоков в пуле определяется возможностями в системе ([подробнее](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx)). Значение ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism нужно задавать если вам нужно по логике приложения ограничить одновременно выполняющиеся операции в единицу времени (например не больше 5, 10 .. n). Для того, что бы увеличить количество реально параллельно выполняющихся операций сначала нужно настроить ThreadPool:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500);
```

Но с этим нужно быть очень осторожным, каждый поток это накладные расходы. И что бы вручную регулировать ThreadPool нужны причины (например вы оптимизируете работу для определённой конфигурации железа).